# Is there a command that outputs a line-numbered file starting the numbering at a specific line?

Tags: text-processing, command

`cat -n file` outputs `file` with line numbering, but how can I specify at which line to start the numbering? Is there a command that can do that?

I've thought of perhaps splitting the process into a few commands. If I want to start line numbering at line `N` of the text file `file.txt`, then:

1. Print the first `N-1` lines, à la `head -$((N-1)) file.txt`
2. Print the remaining `N` lines, numbered: `tail -n N file.txt | cat -n`

But the second step is not possible if the input is from `stdin`; the first step will have consumed all of it. I'd have to create some temporary file to read from and then remove it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk to do this:

```
awk 'NR >= n { printf("%6d  ", NR-n+1) } 1' n=3
```

For lines where the current record number (NR) is greater than or equal to n (passed in as a variable), print a line prefix, starting at 1. The `1` at the end is awk short-hand for printing the current line.

You can also still use `head(1)`, as it stops consuming input when it has read the number of lines it needs:

```
{ head -$((N-1)); cat -n; }
```

You can pipe into that, or redirect a file:

```
cat foo | { head -$((N-1)); cat -n; }
{ head -$((N-1)); cat -n; } < foo
```

Comment: `cat foo | { head -$((N-1)); cat -n; }` doesn't seem to work, it only performs the `head -$((N-1))` portion of it. The `awk` solution seems nice, it doesn't work for files with a million or more lines. The `"%6d"` makes it a tiny bit inflexible, though in reality it will work for most cases.

Comment: @ladaghini: works for me. I have `head (GNU coreutils) 8.13` (head --version).

Comment: @ladaghini: Why does the awk version not work with more than 1 million lines? The result won't be identical to `cat -n`. Change the printf format to whatever suits you.

Comment: The `awk` solution hard codes the amount of padding, which means the output will not align properly should the number of lines be greater than 999999. The cases are few where the number of lines will be that big, but I'm looking for a "perfect" solution.

Comment: My version of head is 8.5. But I don't think that matters much. When I pipe `stdin` from a command, it doesn't work, but when I redirect a file (using <) it works. They problem lay in the piping it seems.

Comment: @ladaghini: But `cat -n` is not a perfect solution - watch what happens at 1,000,000 and 10,000,000. It will never line up unless you have infinite padding. So you need to know how many lines on the input before you can output the first line, but you don't want to make multiple passes. Hope you've got enough memory.

Comment: I guess `cat` is going for a more practical solution of text files likely not being that large. Anyways, thanks for your suggestions.